# How to split word without a separator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', but it still 'hello'.

```
NSString* s = @"hello";
NSArray* arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByString` doesn't quite work like that. Here's the example from Apple:

```
NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

I might try to loop through using `characterAtIndex` and add to mutable array one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Simple using [[NSString UTF8String]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411189-utf8string?language=objc)

It's a property in NSString:

```
@property(readonly) const char *UTF8String;
```

You got this char pointer, then use it as char array.

```
NSString *s = @"hello";
char *sArray = [s UTF8String];

for (int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", sArray[i]);
}
```